# Html extension needing access to IViewEngine; how?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I am having an issue porting an Html extension from .NET Framework to .NET Asp.Net Core!

This is the cshtml file snippet

```
    @if (Model.Length == 0)
    {
        WriteLiteral("No current tasks!");
    }
    <section>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-task" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            @for (var index = 0; index < Model.Length; index++)
            {
                var task = Model[index];
                var viewName = "_" + task.TaskType;
                var exists = Html.PartialViewExists(viewName);
                var vd = new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
            {
                {"index", index}
            };
                vd.Model = task;
                Html.RenderPartial(exists ? viewName : "_Task", task, vd);
            }
        </div>
    </section>
```

The extension `PartialViewExists` extension message looks like this:

```
public static bool PartialViewExists(this HtmlHelper html, string viewName)
{
     var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
     var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
     return result.View != null;
}
```

Converting this to .net core seem to pose a number of issues.

1. There is no Controller hanging off the ViewContext property. Therefore
   I can't get to a ControllerContext
2. Even if I had a ControllerContext I still need an IViewEngine that
   appears to be only available via dependency injection

I cant see a way of doing this in an extension but would love to be proved wrong (dependency injection is good but can be taken too far!)

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested code, but if it doesn't work if should still give you enough to work on.

First problem is you need to know the controller name, you get that from the `html.ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues` collection.

Secondly, to get a view engine, as you're in a static method you don't have automatic dependency injection to rely on so you need to resort to a more hacky service locator pattern.

```
//Some imports...
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;

public static bool PartialViewExists<TModel>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, string viewName)
{
    var controller = html.ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"];

    var viewEngine = (ICompositeViewEngine)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
        .GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine));

    var result = viewEngine.GetView(html.ViewContext.ExecutingFilePath, viewName, false);
    return result.View != null;
}
```

What this says to me is that perhaps you shouldn't be using a static helper for this. Much better to create a proper service that leverages the full DI framework properly and that you can test.

Comment: David thanks for that will look at that today and see if I can get it working... appreciated.

Comment: Ref your comment using the full DI framework, this is an existing app, and that would mean a substantial rewrite and is an anti-pattern for refactoring. So small and incremental changes to the new approach :)